# window not defined error on my Nuxt JS app using leaflet

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, nuxt.js

I can't generate my nuxt app because there is an error on my 'Area' page. The page uses leaflet maps and it seems the error is coming from there.

[image]

I thought wrapping my area component in `<client-only>` would of fixed this but unfortunately it does not.

**Here is my area page:**

```
<template>
  <client-only>
    <div class="area">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Alcaucín</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="area__subheader">
        <h3>Take A Peek</h3>
        <p>View the video below get familiar with what Alcaucín is all about</p>
      </div>
      <!-- ############# INTRO VIDEO ############# -->
      <div class="area__video">
        <iframe
          :src="currentSrc"
          frameborder="0"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        <!-- ############# SELECT VIDEO LANGUAGE ############# -->
        <div class="area__video__lang-toggle">
          <span>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="language"
              id="Eng"
              value="English"
              v-model="videoLanguage"
              @change="changeSrc"
            />
            <label for="Eng">ENG</label>
          </span>
          <span>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="language"
              id="Esp"
              value="Spanish"
              v-model="videoLanguage"
              @change="changeSrc"
            />
            <label for="Esp">ESP</label>
          </span>
          <div
            class="area__video__lang-toggle__selector"
            v-bind:class="[
              {
                toggleEnglish: videoLanguage === 'English',
                toggleSpanish: videoLanguage === 'Spanish',
              },
            ]"
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ############# GENERAL DESCRIPTION ############# -->
      <div class="area__description">
        <h2>"The Traveller That Comes, Never Wants to Leave"</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos,
          eveniet consequatur hic nobis eaque sunt harum excepturi quae possimus
          laboriosam, atque in, eum quod error aut ut voluptatum repellendus id
          ex pariatur cumque saepe suscipit. Doloribus et numquam officiis
          aspernatur saepe deleniti eligendi error perferendis, voluptatem ad
          impedit. Modi, mollitia?
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- ############# INTERACTIVE MAP ############# -->
      <div class="area__map">
        <div id="map-wrap">
          <l-map :zoom="13" :center="[36.9023, -4.1139]" ref="map">
            <l-tile-layer
              url="https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
            ></l-tile-layer>
            <!-- ############# CREATE RESTAURANT MARKERS ############# -->
            <l-marker
              v-for="restaurant in restaurants"
              :key="restaurant.id"
              :lat-lng="restaurant.latlong"
              :icon="eatIcon"
              :ref="restaurant.id"
              v-model="selectedPin.id"
              v-on:click="getPin(restaurant.id)"
            >
              <l-popup
                >{{ restaurant.name }}<br />Restaurant<br />
                <p class="link" @click="lightboxShow = true">
                  More Info
                </p></l-popup
              ></l-marker
            >
            <!-- ############# CREATE HIKING TRAIL MARKERS ############# -->
            <l-marker
              v-for="walk in walks"
              :key="walk.id"
              :lat-lng="walk.latlong"
              :icon="walkIcon"
              :ref="walk.id"
              v-model="selectedPin.id"
              v-on:click="getPin(walk.id)"
            >
              <l-popup
                >{{ walk.name }} <br />Hiking Trail <br />
                <p class="link" @click="lightboxShow = true">
                  More Info
                </p></l-popup
              >
            </l-marker>
          </l-map>
        </div>
        <!-- ############# SHOW CURRENT SELECTED MARKER INFO ############# -->
        <div
          class="lightbox"
          :class="[{ 'show-lightbox': lightboxShow === true }]"
        >
          <div class="title">
            <h3 v-if="selectedPin.name != ''">{{ selectedPin.name }}</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="lightbox__wrapper">
            <img
              v-if="selectedPin.img != ''"
              :src="selectedPin.img"
              class="lightbox__selected-img"
            />
            <h4 v-if="selectedPin.type != ''">{{ selectedPin.type }}</h4>
            <p v-if="selectedPin.description != ''">
              {{ selectedPin.description }}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="lightbox__close-button">
            <button @click="lightboxShow = false">
              <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'times']" />
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ############# IMAGE GALLERY ############# -->
      <div class="area__slider">
        <div v-swiper="swiperOption">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div
              v-for="(image, index) in images"
              :key="'image' + index"
              class="swiper-slide"
            >
              <img
                :src="require(`../assets/AreaPictures${image.imageURL}`)"
                alt=""
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cta">
        <h4>Now it's time to experience it for yourself.</h4>
        <NuxtLink to="/book">
          <button class="buttonPrimary mobileButton">Book Now</button>
        </NuxtLink>
      </div>
    </div>
  </client-only>
</template>

<script>
import json from '@/static/json/locations.json'
import { icon } from 'leaflet'

export default {
  name: 'Area',
  data: function () {
    return {
      // ############# INTRO VIDEO SETTINGS #############
      videoLanguage: 'English',
      englishSrc: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/lRKmJqDbVsY',
      spanishSrc: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/q0WkEkIMmQo',
      currentSrc: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/lRKmJqDbVsY',
      // ############# IMAGE GALLERY SETTINGS #############
      swiperOption: {
        grabCursor: true,
        loop: true,
        autoplay: {
          delay: 5000,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
        },
        map: this.$refs.map,
      },
      // ############# ARRAY TO STORE GALLERY IMAGES #############
      images: [],
      locations: json.locations,
      // ############# ARRAY TO STORE RESTAURANT OBJECTS #############
      restaurants: [],
      // ############# ARRAY TO STORE HIKING TRAIL OBJECTS #############
      walks: [],
      // ############# LEAFLET HIKING TRAIL MARKER ICON #############
      walkIcon: icon({
        iconUrl: '/MapMarkers/hiking.png',
        iconSize: [20, 35],
        iconAnchor: [16, 37],
      }),
      // ############# LEAFLET RESTAURANT MARKER ICON #############
      eatIcon: icon({
        iconUrl: '/MapMarkers/restaurant.png',
        iconSize: [30, 30],
        iconAnchor: [16, 37],
      }),
      // ############# STORE THE CURRENTLY SELECTED LOCATION DATA  #############
      selectedPin: {
        name: '',
        id: '',
      },
      lightboxShow: false,
    }
  },
  // ############# IMPORT THE IMAGES ON MOUNT #############
  mounted() {
    this.importImages(require.context('~/assets/AreaPictures/', true))
    this.importLocations(this.locations)
  },
  methods: {
    changeSrc() {
      if (this.videoLanguage === 'English') {
        this.currentSrc = this.englishSrc
      } else {
        this.currentSrc = this.spanishSrc
      }
    },
    // ############# IMPORT GALLERY IMAGES #############
    importImages(r) {
      r.keys().forEach((key) => {
        var path = key.substring(1) //-----THE PATH FOR SOME REASON CONTAINS A . SO I REMOVE IT
        this.images.push({
          imageURL: path, //----- CREATE A NEW OBJECT AND ADD IT TO IMAGES
        })
      })
    },
    // ############# SPLIT JSON DATA INTO RESTAURANT AND HIKING TRAIL ARRAYS #############
    importLocations() {
      this.restaurants = this.locations.restaurants
      this.walks = this.locations.walks
    },
    // ############# FIND THE DATA OF THE CURRENTLY SELECTED MAP MARKER BY USING ITS ID #############
    getPin(id) {
      let item
      if (id.includes('W')) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.walks.length; i++) {
          item = this.walks[i]
          if (item.id === id) {
            this.selectedPin = item
          }
        }
      } else if (id.includes('R')) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.restaurants.length; i++) {
          item = this.restaurants[i]
          if (item.id === id) {
            this.selectedPin = item
          }
        }
      } else {
        window.alert('Error, no info on marker found')
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Here is my nuxt.config:

```
export default {
    // Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
    head: {
        title: 'casa-isabella',
        meta: [
            { charset: 'utf-8' },
            { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
            { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
        ],
        link: [
            { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
            {
                rel: 'stylesheet',
                href: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css'
            }
        ]
    },

    target: 'static',

    // Global CSS (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css)
    css: [],

    // Plugins to run before rendering page (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins)
    plugins: [
        { src: '~/plugins/VueAwesomeSwiper.js', mode: 'client' },
    ],

    // Auto import components (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components)
    components: true,

    // Modules for dev and build (recommended) (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
    buildModules: [
        '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
        '@nuxtjs/fontawesome'
    ],

    // Modules (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
    modules: [
        // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
        '@nuxtjs/pwa',
        // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/content
        '@nuxt/content',
        '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
        'nuxt-moment', ['nuxt-leaflet', { mode: 'client' }],
        [
            '@nuxtjs/firebase',
            {
                config: {
                    apiKey: '<apiKey>',
                    authDomain: '<authDomain>',
                    projectId: '<projectId>',
                    storageBucket: '<storageBucket>',
                    messagingSenderId: '<messagingSenderId>',
                    appId: '<appId>',
                    measurementId: '<measurementId>'
                },
                services: {
                    auth: true // Just as example. Can be any other service.
                }
            }
        ]

    ],

    // Axios module configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios)
    axios: {},

    // Content module configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-content)
    content: {},

    fontawesome: {
        icons: {
            solid: true
        }
    },


    // Build Configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build)
    build: {},
    devtools: true,
    styleResources: {
        scss: [
            '~/assets/scss/variables.scss',
            '~/assets/scss/button.scss',
            '~/assets/scss/activelink.scss',
            '~/assets/scss/mixins.scss'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you maybe found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to use variables and then a condicional

```
let L
json
if (process.client) {
L = require('leaflet')
json = require('@/static/json/locations.json')
}
```

or you can use the imports to